# UserControl plugin not showing on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, plugins, dll, user-controls

I'm working on some usercontrol plugin system so it's possible to add a dll to a directory and the usercontrol is visible on specified pages.

When I load the control to the page nothing is shown!

Below is some code shown, the simpletestcontrol is compiled in a dll and read in the PluginFactory. (I removed or changed some code to try making is easier to read.)

In Default.aspx.cs the plugin is available and I see when I debug that the control is loaded.. but when I set it in the PluginGrid (a div) nothing is shown when I run the website... What is it that I am missing?

SimpleTestControl.ascx.cs:

```
public partial class SimpleTest : BasePluginControl
{
    public SimpleTest()
        : base(Type.Test)
    {
    }
}
```

SimpleTestControl.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="simpletest.ascx.cs" Inherits="simpletest" %>
TESTESTETS
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="testButton"/>
```

BasePluginControl.cs:

```
public abstract class BasePluginControl : UserControl
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public PluginType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        BasePluginControl plugin =
        PluginFactory.GetPluginByType(PluginType.Test);

        PluginGrid.Controls.Clear();

        if (plugin != null)
        {
            PluginGrid.Controls.Add(plugin);
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

PluginFactory.cs:

```
public static BasePluginControl GetPluginByType(PluginType pluginType)
{
            BasePluginControl plugin = plugins.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PluginType == pluginType);

            if(plugin== null)
                throw new DllNotFoundException("A plugin of the " + pluginType.ToString() + " is not found!");

            return plugin;
        }
public static ICollection<BasePluginControl> LoadPlugins()
        {
            string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PluginPath"];
            plugins.Clear();

            if (!Directory.Exists(path)) 
                return null;

            string[] dllFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll");

            ICollection<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(dllFileNames.Length);
            foreach (string dllFile in dllFileNames)
            {
                AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllFile);
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(an);
                assemblies.Add(assembly);
            }

            IEnumerable<Type> controlPlugins = GetPluginsOf<BasePluginControl>(assemblies);

            foreach (Type controlPlugin in controlPlugins)
            {
                BasePluginControl plugin = (BasePluginControl)Activator.CreateInstance(controlPlugin);

                if (plugin != null)
                    plugins.Add(plugin});
            }

            return plugins;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Type> GetPluginsOf<T>(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
        {
            Type pluginType = typeof(T);
            ICollection<Type> pluginTypes = new List<Type>();
            foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
            {
                if (assembly != null)
                {
                    Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

                    foreach (Type type in types)
                    {
                        if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if( type.GetInterface(pluginType.FullName) != null ||
                                (type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.FullName != null && type.BaseType.FullName.Equals(pluginType.FullName)))
                            {
                                pluginTypes.Add(type);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return pluginTypes;
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
When I add the folliwing code to default.aspx.cs the strBuild variable is empty also...

```
string strBuild;
        // a string writer to write on it
        using (TextWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            // a html writer
            using (HtmlTextWriter renderOnMe = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                // now render the control inside the htm writer
                pluginModel.Control.RenderControl(renderOnMe);

                // here is your control rendered output.
                strBuild = stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
        PluginGrid.InnerHtml = strBuild;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

1. You didn't add the plugin to the pages control's collection, so it won't be processd in the render loop or get tied into the page life cycle.  You either have to add it to a control's collection, or you have to manually render it, by calling Render on the plugin (since it is an ASP.Net Control).
2. It could be the fact that you are loading the dll's in the same domain as the web application.

As such it cannot unload them.  Once loaded, they are loaded.  If they change you will have to reset the application pool to get the new version to load.

Optionally, you should create an AppDomain for your plugins.  Then use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor the plugin directory.

Use the file system watcher to check when files are added, modied, or deleted from the plugin directory.

If the file that changed was a dll, do the following

On Delete: Unload all plugins from the dll from the new AppDomain
On Modified: Unload and Reload the plugins from the App Domain
On Add: Load the plugins from the new dll

Comment: I expected to add this line "this.Page.Controls.Add(plugin);" in the Default.aspx.cs to work... but I guess I'm missing something?